# Is there a shell command for removing trailing decimal places?

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file that looks like this:

```
sx1.1_1.0.loc.08905.3
sx1.1_1.0.loc.08906.3
sx1.1_1.0.loc.08907.2
sx1.1_1.0.loc.08908.3
sx1.1_1.0.loc.08909.4
sx1.1_1.0.loc.08910.1
```

I want it to look like this:

```
sx1.1_1.0.loc.08905
sx1.1_1.0.loc.08906
sx1.1_1.0.loc.08907
sx1.1_1.0.loc.08908
sx1.1_1.0.loc.08909
sx1.1_1.0.loc.08910
```

Does anyone know a quick one liner to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number of fields is unknown:

```
sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' file
```

Matching expression `\.[^.]*$` explanation:

1. `\.` Matches a dot
2. `[^.]*` Matches any sequence of characters NOT containing dots
3. `$` Matches end of line

Answer (score 2):

Its okay, I found an answer:

```
cut -d. -f-5
```